# Issue with an Oracle UDF

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions

I am new to Oracle UDF. I have an Oracle UDF `UDF_DoStuff` like below, which calls a C based UDF `myUDFs.doStuff`.

create or replace

```
FUNCTION UDF_DoStuff (
    str1 IN VARCHAR2,
    str2 IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS output VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   output:= CASE
    WHEN str2 = 'x' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'a')
    WHEN str2 = 'y' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'b')
    ELSE null
END;
RETURN output;   
END;
```

I am trying to modify it to retrieve the username who is running the query and pass that to `myUDFs.doStuff`.

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION UDF_DoStuff (
    str1 IN VARCHAR2,
    str2 IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS output VARCHAR2(50);
uname VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
   select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') into uname from dual;
   output:= CASE
    WHEN str2 = 'x' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'a', uname)
    WHEN str2 = 'y' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'b', uname)
    ELSE null
END;
RETURN output;   
END;
```

However, I am getting the following error near the statement `output:= CASE`. Any thoughts how I can get it to work?

```
Error(10,4): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: at quick glance, looks like your case statement needs an END; added to it

Comment: If you are going to do all of your development in SQL*Plus then it’ll be worth bookmarking the manual for the years ahead https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve041.htm#SQPUG124

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, instead :

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'),
   CASE
    WHEN str2 = 'x' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'a', SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')) 
    WHEN str2 = 'y' THEN myUDFs.doStuff(str1,'b', SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')) 
    ELSE null
    END
into uname, output
from dual;
```

`Case-When` statements are used inside sql, to provide the equivalent of `if-then` statements of `pl/sql`.